# UnavailableException: Not enough replicas available for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE Cassandra Stress

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-stress

I try to make Materialized View tests on our cassandra structure..

I installed Cassandra 3.5 on 6 Node Debian 8 servers from apache repos.

Then I try to run basic stress on it, then I came across with these errors. I can't configure that why I gets this errors.

Here is every node's `cassandra.yaml`

```
cluster_name: 'Cluster'
num_tokens: 256
hinted_handoff_enabled: true
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000 # 3 hours
hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
max_hints_delivery_threads: 2
hints_flush_period_in_ms: 10000
max_hints_file_size_in_mb: 128
batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024
authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator 
authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer
role_manager: CassandraRoleManager
roles_validity_in_ms: 2000
permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000
credentials_validity_in_ms: 2000
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
data_file_directories:
    - /var/lib/cassandra/data
commitlog_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
disk_failure_policy: stop
commit_failure_policy: stop
key_cache_size_in_mb:
key_cache_save_period: 14400
row_cache_size_in_mb: 0
row_cache_save_period: 0
counter_cache_size_in_mb:
counter_cache_save_period: 7200
saved_caches_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000
commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32
seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "195.x.x.192,195.x.x.195"
concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32
concurrent_counter_writes: 32
concurrent_materialized_view_writes: 32
memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers
index_summary_capacity_in_mb:
index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60
trickle_fsync: false
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240
storage_port: 7000
ssl_storage_port: 7001
listen_address: 195.x.x.192 # node ip adress
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
start_rpc: true
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
rpc_port: 9160
broadcast_rpc_address: 195.x.x.255
rpc_keepalive: true
rpc_server_type: sync
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15
incremental_backups: false
snapshot_before_compaction: false
auto_snapshot: true
tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000
column_index_size_in_kb: 64
batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 5
batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb: 50
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16
compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb: 100
sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb: 50
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
cross_node_timeout: false
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch 
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100 
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1
request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler
server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    truststore: conf/.truststore
    truststore_password: cassandra
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    optional: false
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
internode_compression: all
inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false
tracetype_query_ttl: 86400
tracetype_repair_ttl: 604800
gc_warn_threshold_in_ms: 1000
enable_user_defined_functions: false
enable_scripted_user_defined_functions: false
windows_timer_interval: 1
transparent_data_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    chunk_length_kb: 64
    cipher: AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
    key_alias: testing:1
    key_provider: 
      - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.security.JKSKeyProvider
        parameters: 
          - keystore: conf/.keystore
            keystore_password: cassandra
            store_type: JCEKS
            key_password: cassandra
```

**nodetool status :**

```
Datacenter: DC1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address          Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  195.x.x.194  291.61 KB  256          16.7%             0da9c3e0-a0de-4d39-8f94-34f4717c7280  rack1
UN  195.x.x.192  338.54 KB  256          16.2%             ff966a71-f76b-4106-9132-fbfe840fa5e1  rack1
UN  195.x.x.193  293.04 KB  256          17.0%             7cf3488a-d9bb-4b92-87ab-3b98fc6887a1  rack1
Datacenter: DC2
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address          Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  195.x.x.195  264.81 KB  256          16.8%             ca8cf24c-7c1a-4b66-be77-a7c02fdb54ea  rack1
UN  195.x.x.198  288.28 KB  256          17.3%             ed02b226-5830-4aa7-88dd-d6d5f757ed88  rack1
UN  195.x.x.196  285.21 KB  256          15.9%             4c3944c4-1657-48fe-be3e-737fe545b86b  rack1
```

**netstat :**

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 195.x.x.192:7000    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6358/java       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      471/exim4       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7199          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6358/java       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9160            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6358/java       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:35945         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6358/java       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      92/rpcbind      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      97/sshd         
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      92/rpcbind      
tcp6       0      0 0.0.0.0:9042            :::*                    LISTEN      6358/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      97/sshd
```

**Cassanra-stress with thrift mode:**

```
cassandra-stress write n=50000 -rate threads=40 -mode thrift user=x password=x -node {node hostnames}
```

Output:

```
Unable to create stress keyspace: Keyspace names must be case-insensitively unique ("keyspace1" conflicts with "keyspace1")
Sleeping 2s...
Warming up WRITE with 62500 iterations...
Failed to connect over JMX; not collecting these stats
UnavailableException()
UnavailableException()
UnavailableException()
UnavailableException()
UnavailableException()
UnavailableException()
UnavailableException()
UnavailableException()
UnavailableException()
UnavailableException()
java.io.IOException: Operation x10 on key(s) [394e35344e4b34383631]: Error executing: (UnavailableException)

    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Operation.error(Operation.java:138)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Operation.timeWithRetry(Operation.java:116)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.operations.predefined.ThriftInserter.run(ThriftInserter.java:66)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.StressAction$Consumer.run(StressAction.java:329)
Running WRITE with 40 threads for 50000 iteration
Failed to connect over JMX; not collecting these stats
type       total ops,    op/s,    pk/s,   row/s,    mean,     med,     .95,     .99,    .999,     max,   time,   stderr, errors,  gc: #,  max ms,  sum ms,  sdv ms,      mb
UnavailableException()
UnavailableException()
UnavailableException()
UnavailableException()
UnavailableException()
UnavailableException()
UnavailableException()
UnavailableException()
UnavailableException()
UnavailableException()
java.io.IOException: Operation x10 on key(s) [394e35344e4b34383631]: Error executing: (UnavailableException)

    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Operation.error(Operation.java:138)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Operation.timeWithRetry(Operation.java:116)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.operations.predefined.ThriftInserter.run(ThriftInserter.java:66)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.StressAction$Consumer.run(StressAction.java:329)
FAILURE
```

Cassanra-stress with native cql3 mode:

```
cassandra-stress write n=50000 -rate threads=40 -mode native cql3 user=x password=x -node {hostnames}
```

Output:

```
WARN  14:16:12 Error while computing token map for keyspace system_auth with datacenter DC2: could not achieve replication factor 3 (found 1 replicas only), check your keyspace replication settings.
WARN  14:16:12 Error while computing token map for keyspace system_auth with datacenter DC1: could not achieve replication factor 3 (found 1 replicas only), check your keyspace replication settings.
Connected to cluster: COMECluster, max pending requests per connection 128, max connections per host 8
Datatacenter: DC1; Host: /195.x.x.255; Rack: rack1
Datatacenter: DC2; Host: intrinsitymetalsbanka/195.x.x.198; Rack: rack1
Created keyspaces. Sleeping 5s for propagation.
Sleeping 2s...
Warming up WRITE with 62500 iterations...
Failed to connect over JMX; not collecting these stats
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: intrinsitymetalsbanka/195.x.x.198:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replicas available for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)))
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: intrinsitymetalsbanka/195.x.x.198:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replicas available for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)))
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: intrinsitymetalsbanka/195.x.x.198:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replicas available for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)))
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: intrinsitymetalsbanka/195.x.x.198:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replicas available for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)))
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: intrinsitymetalsbanka/195.x.x.198:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replicas available for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)))
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: intrinsitymetalsbanka/195.x.x.198:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replicas available for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)))
at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Operation.error(Operation.java:138)
at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Operation.timeWithRetry(Operation.java:116)
at org.apache.cassandra.stress.operations.predefined.CqlOperation.run(CqlOperation.java:101)
at org.apache.cassandra.stress.operations.predefined.CqlOperation.run(CqlOperation.java:109)
at org.apache.cassandra.stress.operations.predefined.CqlOperation.run(CqlOperation.java:261)
at org.apache.cassandra.stress.StressAction$Consumer.run(StressAction.java:321)
```

Comment: alter keyspace with suitable reflication factor works. If stress tool create new keyspace, you must alter this keyspace and run stress on exist one.